# How to use Mixin in decorators for qooxdoo?

Tags: javascript, css, styling, qooxdoo

In [qooxdoo](http://manual.qooxdoo.org/current/pages/desktop/ui_decorators.html) documentation, there is how to write decorators but there isn't clear way to use it.

So if there any qooxdoo gurus in existance, please enlighten me.

I've tried this :

```
qx.Mixin.define("phwabe.theme.MTextShadow", {
  properties : {
    textShadowColor : {
      nullable : true,
      check : "Color"
    }
  },

  members : {
    _styleTextShadow : function(styles) {
      var color = this.getTextShadowColor();
      if (color === null) {
        return;
      }
      color = qx.theme.manager.Color.getInstance().resolve(color);
      styles["text-shadow"] = color + " 1px 1px";
    }
  }
});

// patch the original decorator class
qx.Class.patch(qx.ui.decoration.Decorator, phwabe.theme.MTextShadow);
```

and this :

```
//in Decoration.js of theme
    "chatitem": {
      style: {
        // width: 1,
        color: "rgba(200,200,200,0.2)",
        textShadowColor: red
      }
```

Only end up with this unknown property error

> phwabe.js?v=e7a4ce2e449b91add3c65027e524a0c7:210 Uncaught Error: No
>   such property: textShadowColor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to patch it :

Your custom mixin :

```
qx.Mixin.define("phwabe.theme.MTextShadow", {
  properties : {
    textShadowColor : {
      nullable : true,
      check : "Color"
    }
  },

  members : {
    _styleTextShadow : function(styles) {
      var color = this.getTextShadowColor();
      if (color === null) {
        return;
      }
      color = qx.theme.manager.Color.getInstance().resolve(color);
      styles["text-shadow"] = color + " 1px 1px";
    }
  }
});
```

//in Decoration.js of theme

```
qx.Class.patch(qx.ui.decoration.Decorator, phwabe.mixins.MTextShadow);
"chatitem": {
  style: {
    // width: 1,
    color: "rgba(200,200,200,0.2)",
    textShadowColor: red
  }
```